# Python regex - Determine answer based on input

Tags: python, regex

I'm wondering if it is possible to use re in Python to find the answer to a question. For example the user is asked a question "Do you wish to continue?";
Can I use regular expressions so that 'y' 'Y' 'YES' 'yes' 'Yes' set a variable to 1, or 'n' 'N' 'No' 'NO' sets a variable to 0? I know that it is possible to do this without using regex, but I'm trying to increase my knowledge of using regular expressions.

Comment: Try to increase your knowledge in regex with better examples. This one is not useful, you won't learn something special about regexes.

Comment: Why not just e.g. `response.lower() in {'y', 'yes'}`? There is no need for regex here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but a regex is overkill for this.  You can do it even more simply than that.  The following code is for Python 3.  You would replace the `input` with `raw_input` and modify the `print` statement for Python 2.

```
>>> def continue_prompt():
...     while True:  # Continue prompting until valid answer.
...         answer = input("Do you want to continue? ")
...         if answer.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
...             cont = True
...             break
...         elif answer.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
...             cont = False
...             break
...         else:
...             print("Please answer yes or no.  ", end="")
...     return cont
...
>>> answer = continue_prompt()
Do you want to continue? foo
Please answer yes or no.  Do you want to continue? y
>>> assert answer == True
>>> answer = continue_prompt()
Do you want to continue? yes
>>> assert answer == True
>>> answer = continue_prompt()
Do you want to continue? NO
>>> assert answer == False
>>> answer = continue_prompt()
Do you want to continue? N
>>> assert answer == False
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just seeing if something like this was possible to do using regex but like you said, I guess its overkill.

Comment: Not a problem.  I use regex very, very rarely.  When I was a young Python programmer (all of a year ago), someone said that it's possible to do most of what you can do with `regex` much more simply using an `in` or the string `find()` method.  That being said, there are a lot of use cases where only a regex will do, so it's a good tool to have in your arsenal.

Answer (score 4):

For example, you can validate with optional groups like so:

```
re.search(r'[yY](?:es)?', user_input) # es is option but requires a y
```